# Using query result as subquery syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I need to identify duplicate entries to delete them. I can find the duplicates using the following query

```
select s.*, t.* 
from [tableXYZ] s
join (
    select [date], [product], count(*) as qty
    from [tableXYZ]
    group by [date], [product]
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.[date] = t.[date] and s.[product] = t.[product]
ORDER BY s.[date], s.[product], s.[id]
```

and then need to use the result from this table to show where `[fieldZ] IS NULL`

I've tried the following but get error `The column 'date' was specified multiple times for 'subquery'.`

```
select * from
(
    select s.*, t.* 
    from [tableXYZ] s
    join (
        select [date], [product], count(*) as qty
        from [tableXYZ]
        group by [date], [product]
        having count(*) > 1
    ) t on s.[date] = t.[date] and s.[product] = t.[product]
) as subquery
where [fieldZ] is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have column date in your subquery twice because you are selecting `s.*` and `t.*`, this will return `s.Date` and `t.date`.  If you need both columns, alias one of the columns.

You will also run into this problem with the `product` column.  Your subquery cannot return multiple columns with the same name.   Only select the columns you need in your subquery instead of selecting all columns.  This is a good practice in general and will solve this issue.

Comment: Just to add emphasis... we have a standard that no SQL should ever use "*" for production code.  We use it purely as a debugging aid to quickly prototype queries and test things only. ALWAYS list all the columns you're actually interested in, and ONLY those you're actually interested in for any given query.